# Client side validate part of page in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side, validation

I have a view with a single begin form HTML attribute. Inside the form, I have two sections and inside each section I have few fields and a button to update those fields. I am using a single model for both sections.

My problem is when I do client side validation on click of button in section 1 even section 2 is getting validated which I don't want to validate.

So basically I want to validate each section individually on client side using single form attribute and a single model.

My model class

```
Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Current Password.")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)] 
public string Password { get; set; } 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter New Password.")] 
[DataType(DataType.Password)] 
public string NewPassword { get; set; } 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Confirm Password.")] 
[DataType(DataType.Password)] 
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "New password must match Confirm Password")] 
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: please provide model class so better understand.how to create html this also important.provide some code for better solution.

Comment: what i will understand to, you combine two model in one controller. that is you want.

Comment: sorry for previous post i have to use a single model only. i dont used seperate models for my sections on the page.

Answer (score 0):

so you have some time some of the field is required and some of the time is not required that is your problem. remove required in model class add to client side like this way.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user_password, new { @class = "required", 
@type = "password" })
```

but i worn you to please check manually validation in control.